# Angular TimelineLite time function doesn't work with OnInit

Tags: angular, gsap

I try to implement a progress bar and a timer using TimelineLite:

HTML:

```
<div id="progress"></div>
{{timeline.time()}}
```

CSS:

```
#progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

[image]

Here's what I want:
When the page loads, the progress bar starts animating from 100% to 0% width (10 sec. duration). Also, I want to show the result of the `time` function.
Here's what I did:

```
public timeline = new TimelineLite();

ngOnInit() {
  this.start();
}

start() {
  const progress = document.getElementById('progress');
  this.timeline.fromTo(progress, 10, {width: '100%'}, {width: 0, ease: Linear.easeNone});
}
```

So when the page loads, the progress bar works but the timer doesn't. I don't know why. If I try to set a timeout for 3 seconds at `ngOnInit`, it works:

```
ngOnInit() {
  setTimeout(() => this.start(), 3000);
}
```

Also if I create a button than invokes `start` function at click, it works:

```
<button (click)="start()">Start</button>
```

So the problem is that the timer doesn't work if I try to invoke `fromTo` function from `ngOnInit`.

Comment: It works for me, as you can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/gsap-demo-6pah3d?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts). In [this other stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/gsap-demo-vhtlvs), I simulate a case where the `div` is not initially present due to an `ngIf` condition, how you can detect when it is available, and call `start` at that moment.

Comment: @ConnorsFan, yes, it works on StackBlitz, but on my local machine it doesn't. Could you please take a look at my repository https://github.com/BorisZubchenko/TimelineLiteTimer. It contains identical code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi  you should use `@ViewChild` to target your elements and use `AfterViewInit` lifeCycleHook when you want to manipulate | access to your DOMElement (current component or child component).

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('progress') progressElement: ElementRef;

  constructor(private changeRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { } 

  public timeline = new TimelineLite();
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.start();
  }

  start() {
    this.timeline.eventCallback('onUpdate', () => {
      this.time = this.timeline.time();
      this.changeRef.detectChanges();
    }, [] );

    // Here i use the ViewChild Binding instead of pure javascript fetching.
    this.timeline.fromTo(this.progressElement.nativeElement, 10, {width: '100%'}, {width: 0, ease: Linear.easeNone});
  }
}
```

To facilitate your testing i have does [Github Pull request](https://github.com/BorisZubchenko/TimelineLiteTimer/pull/2). Anyone which read your original question can easily see the difference.

---

Update 1 : on your view, you call a function which return the current timer from TimelineLite. Because is just function call, it will not be called again and again on each internal TimelineLite update.

To do it, you have to use [TimelineLite event binding](https://greensock.com/docs/TimelineLite/eventCallback).

Now, by default your view will not be "updated" each time you update your attribute from following code :

```
this.timeline.eventCallback('onUpdate', () => {
  // angular is not inform by default than something happen here.
 }, [] );
```

is why, you should use `ChangeDetectorRef` to force angular to detect the freshest updated component attribute.

*pull requested updated*

Comment: Hi, thanks for your PR. The problem is that the progress bar works, but the timer doesn't. Your solution does not fix my problem.

Comment: oh i see, i have updated my stackoverflow post and my pull request.

Answer (score 0):

This is evidently a case of timeline of calling lifecycle methods of angular. Highly likely the problem is in onInit where you don't get DOM element `progress` immediately. You have made to it to work applying `settimeout` other way is to keep an `setinterval` until you find `progress`.
Seemingly the best way is to write `this.start()` in `ngAfterViewInit()` instead of `ngOnInit()`

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it happens because timeout starts after the template initialized and then the code runs, outside OnInit. I am not sure though.

You may want to use zone.run() here.

Here is a link, which may turn out to be helpful for you: https://medium.com/@MertzAlertz/what-the-hell-is-zone-js-and-why-is-it-in-my-angular-2-6ff28bcf943e